# How can I make a recurring async task (I don't control where asyncio.run() is called)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm using a library that itself makes the call to `asyncio.run(internal_function)` so I can't control that at all. I do however have access to the event loop, it's something that I pass into this library.

Given that, is there some way I can set up an recurring async event that will execute every X seconds while the main library is running.

This doesn't exactly work, but maybe it's close?

```py
import asyncio
from third_party import run

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

async def periodic():
    while True:
        print("doing a thing...")
        await asyncio.sleep(30)

loop.create_task(periodic())

run(loop) # internally this will call asyncio.run() using the given loop
```

The problem here of course is that the task I've created is never awaited. But I can't just await it, because that would block.

Edit: Here's a working example of what I'm facing. When you run this code you will only ever see "third party code executing" and never see "doing my stuff...".

```py
import asyncio

# I don't know how the loop argument is used
# by the third party's run() function,
def third_party_run(loop):
    async def runner():
        while True:
            print("third party code executing")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

    # but I do know that this third party eventually runs code
    # that looks **exactly** like this.
    try:
        asyncio.run(runner())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()


async def periodic():
    while True:
        print("doing my stuff...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


loop.create_task(periodic())

third_party_run(loop)
```

If you run the above code you get:

```
third party code executing
third party code executing
third party code executing
^CTask was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<periodic() running at example.py:22>>
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:674: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'periodic' was never awaited
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `await` on a created task.

It will run in the background as long as the event loop is active and is not stuck in a CPU bound operation.

According to your comment, you don't have an access to the event loop. In this case you don't have many options other than running in a different thread (which will have its own loop), or changing the loop creation policy in order to get the event loop, which is a very bad idea in most cases.

Comment: When I run the code I never see the `do a thing...` being printed. When I Ctrl+C the process to kill it I see this log: [2022-12-01 14:51:45][asyncio][ERROR] - Task was destroyed but it is pending!

Comment: @user27930 That's because `asyncio.run()` creates a new event loop. So you don't actually have access to the event loop. If you would have access to the event loop, the code would run correctly. (Try running with `loop.run_until_complete(runner())`)

Comment: Yep, I just dug into the code a bit and I see that the old version of the library accepted a `loop` argument, but the newer version I'm using now doesn't seem to honor it at all and just calls `asyncio.run()` directly.

Any options to getting around this and making a periodic task with this limitation?

Comment: Best way? If you have anything in the library (you still haven't said which library it is). Worst way? Changing the loop policy . You can make sure the next time a new event loop is spawned it's the same one as the one you attached your task to.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make your test program run.  However, it's a hack.  It could fail, depending on the internal design of your third party library.  From the information you provided, the library has been structured to be a black box.  You can't interact with the event loop or schedule a callback.  It seems like there might be a very good reason for this.

If I were you I would try to contact the library designer and let him know what your problem is.  Perhaps there is a better solution.  If this is a commercial project, I would make 100% certain that the team understands the issue, before attempting to use my below solution or anything like it.

The script below overrides one method (`new_event_loop`) in the DefaultEventLoopPolicy.  When this method is called, I create a task in this loop to execute your `periodic` function.  I don't know how often, or for what purpose, the library will call this function.  Also, if the library internally overrides the EventLoopPolicy then this solution will not work.  In both of these cases it may lead to unforeseeable consequences.

OK, enough disclaimers.

The only significant change to your test script was to replace the infinite loop in runner with a one that times out.  This allowed me to verify that the program shuts down cleanly.

```
import asyncio

# I don't know how the loop argument is used
# by the third party's run() function,
def third_party_run():
    async def runner():
        for _ in range(4):
            print("third party code executing")
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

    # but I do know that this third party eventually runs code
    # that looks **exactly** like this.
    try:
        asyncio.run(runner())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        return

async def periodic():
    while True:
        print("doing my stuff...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

class EventLoopPolicyHack(asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__running = None
        super().__init__()
        
    def new_event_loop(self):
        # Override to create our periodic task in the new loop
        # Get a loop from the superclass.
        # This method must return that loop.
        print("New event loop")
        loop = super().new_event_loop()
        if self.__running is not None:
            self.__running.cancel()  # I have no way to test this idea
        self.__running = loop.create_task(periodic())
        return loop
    
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(EventLoopPolicyHack())

third_party_run()
```

Comment: I never would have thought of that! Really interesting idea, but yeah, I understand the need for all the disclaimers here :)

I think perhaps the best solution for my use case is to use the threading package rather than trying to work with the event loop. Like you said, the library is a bit of a black box and I don't want to step on its toes.